# Gtmetrix: avoid bad requests

Tags: errors, html

Gtmetrix is showing avoid bad requests, and saying

> The following requests are returning 404/410 responses. Either fix the broken links or remove the references to the non-existent resources.

The references are:

> my_website/wp-content/cache/min/1/0a0a963a44e000841056cbe07ff4b7af.js
>    my_website/wp-content/cache/min/1/4f72d5086a7731e8c76e84bfed04fb79.css

I am using wp-rocket and until a few days ago everything was fine. 
How do I remove these references?
any help will be much-appreciated
thanks in advance.

Comment: Third party plugin questions are considered off topic here, you should ask the WP Rocket support

Comment: The WP Rocket is a third party plugin, and such questions are here [off-topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please consult the appropriate support forum for the plugin. Maybe [this](https://docs.wp-rocket.me/article/106-my-site-is-broken#minify) or [this](https://docs.wp-rocket.me/article/19-resolving-issues-with-file-optimization) will be helpful.

Comment: apologies I was not aware it was a wp rocket issue I was just stating I use wp rocket. I just assumed wp-content would be allowed on here many thanks